# Read lines and match against pattern in error log

Tags: shell-script

I have requirement to read log file against pattern.

Log file can grow with exception and pattern. in below example i have to read whole line from  and  against pattern 000451 and send in email. how to do it using shell scripts. since it in log file so in every 5 minutes i  have to read pattern and send email if pattern matches .

```
<MqException: BEGIN>
Code: SQL-8201: Database error. SQL state . Database specific error code (if any) was 0. Database error message (if any) was: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: 000451: 
EXCEPTIONMESSAGE: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000451: The connection manager is shutdown: java:jboss/eCMDataSource
STACKTRACE: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: 000451: 
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:137)
        at com.tibco.mdm.infrastructure.db.DBUtil.getConnection(DBUtil.java:643)
        at com.tibco.mdm.infrastructure.config.dao.StickyConfigurationDocumentDAO.updateDocument(StickyConfigurationDocumentDAO.java:93)


EXCEPTIONMESSAGE: javax.resource.ResourceException: 000451: The connection manager is shutdown: 
ERRORMESSAGE: Failed to get connection.
<MqException: END>
```

your help appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

schedule this script to run for every 5 or 10 minutes.

it will just compare the old alert and new count from the logs.

change the DB_LOG_FILE and your email id in the script

```
#!/bin/bash

EXTRACT_FILE=/tmp/$(date +%Y%m%d).txt
touch ${EXTRACT_FILE}
DB_LOG_FILE=/tmp/db.log

PREV_COUNT=$(wc -l < ${EXTRACT_FILE})

grep "000451" ${DB_LOG_FILE} > ${EXTRACT_FILE}
CURRENT_COUNT=$(wc -l < ${EXTRACT_FILE})

if [ "${PREV_COUNT]" -ne "${CURRENT_COUNT}" ]
then
    mail -s "Database Error Found" "abc@xyz.com" < ${EXTRACT_FILE}
else
    echo "No new alerts"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working and reading line EXCEPTIONMESSAGE ,STACKTRACE while i want to read from <MqException: BEGIN> to <MqException: END>. whole exception message. please help

Comment: and also want only those lines during particular time exception occurred not whole log file exception which is having code "000451"